# Time complexity in BST

Tags: data-structures, time-complexity, binary-search-tree

In what situation, searching a term using a binary search tree requires a time complexity that is linear to the size of the term vocabulary (say M)? How to ensure a worst time complexity of log M?

Comment: You can have self balancing trees like AVL trees, otherwise in worst case, the binary tree will be skewed (left or right) and it will be having worst case time complexity equivalent to number of elements in the tree......

Answer (score 1):

A complete binary tree is one for which every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled.  The worst case search peformance is the height of the tree, which in this case would be `O(lgM)`, assuming `M` vocabulay terms in the tree.

One way to ensure this performance would be to use a self-balancing tree, e.g. a red-black tree.

Answer (score 0):

Since binary search is a divide-and-conquer algorithm, we can ensure O(log M) if the tree is balanced, with equal number of terms under the sub-trees of any node. O(log M) basically means that time goes up linearly while M goes up exponentially. If it takes 1 second to search a balanced binary tree that is 10 nodes, it’d take 2 seconds to search an equally balanced tree with 100 nodes, 3 seconds to search 1000 nodes, and so on.

But if the binary search tree is extremely unbalanced to the point where it looks a lot like a linked list, we would have to go through every node, requiring a time complexity that is linear to M.